# Running a while loop if keys aren't in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement, while-loop

I'm currently trying to build a very simple program where the user is asked to choose a path and based on the path chosen I want to update a dictionary. It seems when the user chooses path_2b first it moves on and prints “congrats on finishing the game” and stops running even when only path_2b has been added to the dictionary when it should only stop running when both paths are present.. I'm just starting to learn the ropes of Python and programming in general so any help and tips are appreciated!

```
user_save = {}

def start_button():
    def path_2a():
        if "path_1" in user_save:
            print("You've already taken this path.")
        else:
            user_save["path_1"] = "completed"
            print("Congrats on finishing this path!")
    def path_2b():
        if "path_2" in user_save:
            print("You've alredy taken this path.")
        else:
            user_save["path_2"] = "Completed"
            print("Congrats on finishing this path!")

    chosen_path = input("Would you like to choose path 2A or 2B?: ").lower()
    if chosen_path == "2a":
        path_2a()
    elif chosen_path == "2b":
        path_2b()
    else:
        print("Sorry that isn't a valid path. Please try again.")

while ("path_1" and "path_2") not in user_save:
    start_button()
if "path_1" and "path_2" in user_save:
    print("Congrats on finishing the game!")
```

I would like the loop to keep running until the user has chosen both paths 1 and 2. Once both keys are in the dictionary I want to print a congrats message and break the loop. Like I said before most of the code runs fine. If the user chooses path_2a first and then 2b the loops does exactly what I want it to even if they choose a path that isn't there. It's only when the user chooses path_2b first. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `("path_1" and "path_2") not in user_save` and `"path_1" and "path_2" in user_save` don't do what you think they do.

Comment: You said that the loop breaks, what is the error?

Comment: `("path_1" and "path_2")` always returns `True` so your while loop is equivalent to `True not in user_save` which is definitely not what you are looking for. You need to expand out each clause, `"path_1" not in user_save and "path_2" not in user_save` or look into the `all()` builtin.

Comment: I should correct myself. The loop doesn’t “break” but it seems when the user chooses path_2b first it moves on and prints “congrats on finishing the game” and stops running even when only path_2b has been added to the dictionary when it should only stop running when both paths are present.

Comment: I tried to expand out the not in clause but I ended up with the same problem. Where exactly should I use all()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting functions within functions, try the following.  I've simplified it to use "2a" and "2b" as the actual key names.  Also, since having both 2a and 2b determines when you want to exit, you can skip the `while` loop and just use a single function that exits when 2a and 2b have been chosen, but keeps running otherwise.

```
def play_game(user_save):
    chosen_path = input("Would you like to choose path 2A or 2B?: ").lower()

    if chosen_path not in ['2a', '2b']:
        print("Sorry that isn't a valid path. Please try again.")
    elif chosen_path in user_save:
        print("You've already taken this path.")
    else:
        user_save[chosen_path] = "Completed"
        print("Congrats on finishing this path!")

    # If both 2a and 2b have been taken, just "return" to exit.
    if '2a' in user_save and '2b' in user_save:
        print("Congrats on finishing the game!")
        return

    # If they're still here, loop it again. Take the updated
    # dictionary <user_save> as input for the next round.
    play_game(user_save)


# Run the program
user_save = {}
play_game(user_save)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! The logic there seems much simpler and more efficient. I didn't know you could use a function that way I thought you would need a loop to do that. Currently teaching myself so everything helps. I do have one question about you code though. With the if '2a' in user_save and '2b' in user_save: statement, could that potentially cause conflicts if there were other data types aside from the list in the dictionary? What type of data is '2a' and '2b' exactly?

Comment: You're welcome!  The '2a' and '2b' are just strings themselves.  If your keys are not strings (e.g., your dictionary is something like '{1: "completed", 2: "completed"}') then you'd have to check for integers. Though another consideration is that if you're only checking whether a key is in a dictionary, you could just use a list instead of a dictionary (e.g., if path 2a is taken, then `append` "2a" to a list). And yes, having a command within a function to call itself (a.k.a. "recursion" or a "recursive function") is another helpful way you can "loop" something.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code you need to change your code :

```
user_save = {}

def start_button():
    def path_2a():
        if "path_1" in user_save:
            print("You've already taken this path.")
        else:
            user_save["path_1"] = "completed"
            print("Congrats on finishing this path!")
    def path_2b():
        if "path_2" in user_save:
            print("You've alredy taken this path.")
        else:
            user_save["path_2"] = "Completed"
            print("Congrats on finishing this path!")

    chosen_path = input("Would you like to choose path 2A or 2B?: ").lower()
    if chosen_path == "2a":
        path_2a()
    elif chosen_path == "2b":
        path_2b()
    else:
        print("Sorry that isn't a valid path. Please try again.")

while  "path_2" not in user_save or "path_1" not in user_save:
    start_button()

if "path_2" in user_save and "path_1" in user_save:
    print("Congrats on finishing the game!")
```